# Calculate cumulative sum over partitions with gaps in SQL

Tags: mysql, loops, common-table-expression, recursive-cte

I have a table with stock changes with different countries and different products.
The table looks like the following:

| Date | Country | Product | Variation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 | Spain | Pen | 1 |
| 2023-10-01 | Germany | Pen | 1 |
| 2023-10-01 | Germany | Pen | -1 |
| 2023-9-01 | Italy | Pen | 1 |
| 2023-09-01 | Italy | Pen | 5 |
| 2023-09-01 | Germany | Pencil | 2 |
| 2023-08-01 | Spain | Pencil | 1 |

I am trying to write a query on mysql 8+ that can summarize the stock of the warehouse grouped by month, by product and by country.

The result should be something like this for October and September:

| Date | Country | Product | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| October 23 | Italy | Pencil | 5 |
| October 23 | Italy | Pen | 1 |
| October 23 | Spain | Pencil | 2 |
| October 23 | Spain | Pen | 3 |
| October 23 | Germany | Pencil | 2 |
| October 23 | Germany | Pen | 3 |
| September 23 | Italy | Pencil | 2 |
| September 23 | Italy | Pen | 1 |
| September 23 | Spain | Pencil | 4 |
| September 23 | Spain | Pen | 1 |
| September 23 | Germany | Pencil | 2 |
| September 23 | Germany | Pen | 3 |

The problem is that there are gaps in some countries or some products that do not allow me to perform a simple cumulative sum with partitions.
For example:

```
SELECT
Date,
Product,
Country,
SUM(SUM(variation)) OVER (PARTITION BY Product, Country ORDER BY Date)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Date,Country,Product
```

The only solution I can think of is to create a procedure with loops on the dates and calculate the totals at each loop, is there any other more efficient solution to avoid the gaps? Maybe using recursive CTE ?

Thank you,

Comment: Please add sample data as text which we can use - as opposed to images which we can't

Comment: Done with tables sorry

Comment: You have a calendar table, a product table and a country table?

Comment: No but we can perform a distinct select if needed.

Comment: For that to work you need as a minimum 1 date for every date, 1 entry for every country and 1 entry for every product - if that works for you use a cte to cross join every element adding a zero variant and go from there. btw it's better if your desired outcome can be derived from sample data

Comment: *there are gaps in some countries or some products* You must gather the list of products and countries (the best way - store these lists in  separate tables) and generate the list of dates then leftjoin your data to these lists.

Answer (score 0):

What does this give you?

```
SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(DATE, "%M-%y"),
        Product,
        Country,
        SUM(variation) AS sum_v
    FROM  mytable
    WHERE Date >= '2023-09-01'
      AND Date  < '2023-09-01' + INTERVAL 2 MONTH
    GROUP BY  Date, Country, Product
```

I don't understand the issue with gaps.

As Akina points out, a `LEFT JOIN` with a table containing all date would give you NULLs for days with no data.  `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()` can then turn `NULL` into `0`.

If the above does not give you the final result, show us what you need.